# Do I need to add an ODBC Connection to Azure Databricks? If so, how?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, azure, databricks

I am trying to do run a simple a df.to_sql() process and I'm getting the following error.

> Can't open lib 'Simba Spark ODBC Driver' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=server_name.database.windows.net;DATABASE=my_db;UID=my_id;PWD=my_pw")
myeng = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)


df.to_sql(name="dbo.my_table", con=myeng, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

If I look in Cluster > Configuration > Advanced Options > JDBC/ODBC, I don't see any reference to ODBC.  I see some JDBC stuff, and that's it.  I'm not completely sure how to proceed here.  If anyone can offer some guidance as to how to make this work, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try  connecting ODBC driver in databricks. https://docs.databricks.com/en/integrations/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#odbc-windows